# Design of MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design

My supervisor asked to design a database by using MySQL.  This database is used to store information about evaluation surveys.  The survey has a lot of questions, and each question has 5 choices, the user choose the answer, and then the system evaluate the scores by the answer.  Basically, my supervisor wants me to create a database that stores information about surveys, and also the results of each survey.  Could anybody give me an idea how to start it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience in this domain, but a quick Google of "open source survey software mysql" gives 874,000 results. What I recommend that you do is to download a few of these - see how they organise their database schema(s) and adopt and adapt your own schema to what's been done already. As Newton said, stand on the [shoulders of giants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_on_the_shoulders_of_giants). You could also take code if you can read the particular langauage in which it's written - (PHP, Perl, Python - whatever).

Your question is very broad and vague and probably outside of the guidelines for the forum - take the tour and also the "[help us to help you](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/)" blog - both at the bottom of the page. These forums are a great resource and you will gain a lot by following the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

First, think of a database (in MySQL or otherwise) as a place to store raw data.  After you design that, then think about how the data needs to be processed.  It may -- or may not -- be possible for SQL statements to do some, or all, of the processing.

Your specification has *possibly* left out some information, such as what you need to store about the users that take the survey.

So, perhaps one Database with a few Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
user_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_name ...
etc...
PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Questions (
q_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
question VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (q_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Answers (
user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, -- for JOINing to Users
q_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, -- for JOINing to Questions
answer CHAR(1) NOT NULL, -- 'a'..'e' -- assuming those are the possible answers
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, q_id)
);
```

Maybe that will help you get started.  Suggest you take the online MySQL tutorial, too.